# underscore.js _.values method reverses the order

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

The `_.values` function of underscore.js reverses the order of values returned.

Does anyone know the reason behind this behavior?

Comment: It shouldn't.  Please give more details of your situation.

Answer (score 8):

[`_.values`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#values) works on objects. The order of properties **is not defined** (it is implementation-dependent and may vary even within an implementation in non-obvious ways). From section 12.6.4 ("The `for-in` statement") of [the ECMAScript specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm):

> The mechanics and order of enumerating the properties...is not specified.

Underscore either uses `for..in` or `Object.keys` to get the property names, and then get the values. The order of `Object.keys` is slaved to the order of `for..in` (see Section 15.2.3.14).

Comment: Spot on. Added some spec refs.

Comment: @T.J.: Nice, thank you :) I will transfer any additional up vote to an answers of yours :D